# Finding whether a binary search tree is perfect?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I need to find if the binary tree is a perfect binary tree, meaning that each node has 2 nodes except for the last level. These are the methods I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working and I'm pretty much stuck on finding it. Any ideas?

```
private boolean isPerfect(BinaryNode<AnyType> t){

    int sizeTree = size(t);

    double num =  Math.log(sizeTree+1)/Math.log(2);  

    int checkNum = (int) (Math.floor(num));

    if(num - checkNum == 0)
        return true;
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That returns `true` when you find a leaf and does pretty much nothing else

Comment: suppose isPerfect(t, left) is false and isPerfect(t, right) is also false; then your `if` returns true.

Comment: You need to find the height of the tree. Then you should count the leaf nodes and you are done. A perfect BST has to have 2^N leaves where N is the height of the tree.

Comment: @Ayberk, that's too naive

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what definition italianmoses is using but according to this site that is correct: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/perfectBinaryTree.html

Comment: I figured out the algorithm for it. Using my size() method, I took the idea of 2^(n) - 1 nodes in a tree and compared it to powers of two. I'll post the code when it lets me.

Answer (score 5):

Since this sounds like "a learning exercise", here's a hint :

- Compare the minimum and maximum tree node depths.

Note: this is only one approach ... but it should be enough to get you thinking.

---

@phcoding's comment points out that your problem here may actually be a mismatch between alternative definitions of "perfect search tree".  Your code should work in the case where there are exactly `2^N` leaf nodes (arranged correctly).

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree ... and look for the definitions of "full", "complete" and "perfect" binary trees.

Comment: I trashed the answer I was writing in spite of this one. I prefer this tip than the real code I was gonna post

Comment: @Alexander - I think you mean "trashed" :-)

Comment: I figured out the algorithm for it. Using my size() method, I took the idea of 2^(n) - 1 nodes in a tree and compared it to powers of two. I'll post the code when it lets me.